# What values can be represented with BitVecs in z3?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, bitvector

I think I don't understand how BitVecs work in z3. I have written the following code:

```
>>> import z3
>>> s = z3.Solver()
>>> a = z3.BitVec("a", 32)
>>> s.add(z3.ForAll(a, z3.Not(z3.And(a > 2147483647, a < 2147484671))))
```

I'd expect that this to be "unsat", because there are values inside and outside this range. But when I run `s.check()`, I get:

```
>>> s.check()
sat
```

This was confusing to me, so I guessed there was overflow involved. But then I tried:

```
>>> b = z3.BitVec("b", 32)
>>> s = z3.Solver()
>>> s.add(b == 2147484671)
>>> s.check()
sat
>>> s.model()
[b = 2147484671]
```

Which confuses me a lot, because it suggests that z3 can model this number using 32 bit BitVecs. Additionally I ran:

```
>>> s = z3.Solver()
>>> c = z3.BitVec("c", 32)
>>> s.add(z3.And(c > 2147483647, c < 2147484671))
>>> s.check()
unsat
```

Which confused me even more, because it seems clearly incompatible with the second example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operators > and < are signed.
2147484671 is a negative number when interpreted as a 32-bit number. That's why you constraint is unsat.
You can use UGT/ULT instead of >/< to ignore the sign bit.

Bottom line: bit vectors represent numbers, but you need to know what's the signedness of the operations you are using.  In the Python API, all operator overloads are signed operations.